# Using sessions in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is my code using sessions in C# for login. I have business logic and data access layer written for this, but my code is not working as expected. Even if there is no record in DB, i am able to login and it redirects to `error.aspx`

Default.aspx.cs

```
public void LoginButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int id;

    if (LoginName.Text!=""&& Password.Text!="")
    {
        try
        {
            sessionVars = BL_Authenticate.AuthenticateUser(sessionVars, LoginName.Text, Password.Text);

            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Session["Exception"] = ex.Message.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
        }

        //else
        //{
        //    Response.Redirect("error.aspx");

        //}
        if (sessionVars.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
        {
            try
            {
                Session["User"] = (string)sessionVars.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"];
                Session["User"] += (string)" ";
                Session["User"] += (string)sessionVars.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Session["Exception"] = ex.Message.ToString();
                Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
            }
            id = (int)sessionVars.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
            if (id >= 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    Session["Role"] = "Admin";
                    FormsAuthentication.Authenticate((string)sessionVars.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Login"], (string)sessionVars.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"]);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Session["Exception"] = ex.Message.ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
                }
                if (FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl("Admin", false) == "/UserInterface/home.aspx")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("admin", false);
                    Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
                }
                else
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("admin", false);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Role"] = "User";
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("user", false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage.Text = "Sorry, wrong username or password.";
        }
    }

}
```

}

BL_Authenticate

```
public class BL_Authenticate
{
    public static DataSet AuthenticateUser(DataSet user, string login, string password)

    {
        return DAL_Authenticate.AuthenticateUser(user, login, password);
    }
}
```

DAL_Authenticate

```
public static DataSet AuthenticateUser(DataSet dataset, string login, string password)
{
    try
    {

        //Dispose all objects that have a .Dispose()

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        conn = DAL_DataBaseConnection.GetConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("authentication", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
        param.Value = login;
        param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
        param.Value = password;
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

Comment: Please at least post code that will compile. There's a `catch` block in there with no matching `try`.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry: that was missed when i am modifying my code

Comment: @DavidG Can you plz help me now

Comment: One normal thing I see is that if the login fails, it redirect to an error page, so there is no mistake there, are you sure your login as work at that point ?

Comment: @Antoine There is no login fail at this point. Its accepting all the logins even though i have created in my DB as only one login as UserName: Admin and Password Admin. Even if i give that also it redirect to error page

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text - store a salted hash of the password instead. [Secure Password Authentication Explained Simply](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54164/Secure-Password-Authentication-Explained-Simply)

Comment: Well that is the logic i'm seeing, your code dosen't necessarily accept the login just because it redirect to error page, it's the other way around, if the login had worked, it would not have redirect to error page, but home page... homepage is the page you see when login works !

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes after successful login it should redirect to homepage  but instead it is moving to error page. Instead of Admin if i enter a also as username and password it acce'pts

Comment: You know how to put a Break Point ? Put one at the beginning of that function and tell me in WITCH catch{ } does the redirect("error") happen.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes i have put break point and it directly go to catch and shows error page after if (LoginName.Text!=""&& Password.Text!=""). It is not gong to try

Comment: then it means the function BL_Authenticate.AuthenticateUser() is problematic, it can only be the sessionVars to me.

Answer (score 0):

One normal thing I see is that if the login fails, it redirect to an error page, so there is no mistake there, are you sure your login as work at that point ?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. :)